# Pressing RET inserts unnecessary whitespace

Tags: indentation

My Emacs  inserts whitespace on the next line if the current line starts with whitespace. IE

```
   a<RET>
   <--- whitespace
```

This happens across modes (python, text-mode, fundamental-mode), and versions (24.5, 26.3). How do I get turn this off? (to be more like `nano` or `pico` behavior)? This messing with my terminal's copy-paste

Comment: When you paste into the terminal, your terminal is supposed to tell Emacs that this is a paste which completely avoids this problem.  This was supported in Emacs-24, but it should definitely work in Emacs-26, so if you see the problem when pasting into your terminal with Emacs-26, it's presumably a problem with your terminal or a bug in Emacs.  Please report it.

Comment: It seems likely that my terminal (iterm2) treats copy/paste equivalently to typing the text manually (ie, there's an option to "paste slowly"). How is "this is a copy/paste" signaling supposed to work exactly?

Comment: iterm2 is supposed to have support for "bracketed paste" (as do most terminal emulators nowadays) so if paste misbehaves in Emacs-26, please `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Emacs 25, they changed the default behavior of `RET`.  Previously (prior to Emacs 25) `RET` just inserted a newline char (taking you to the beginning of the next line), and `C-j` did what `RET` does now: inserts a newline char and then indents according to the previous line's code.

You can restore the previous default behavior this way (it's what I do):

```lisp
(when (fboundp 'electric-indent-mode)
  (electric-indent-mode -1)) ; Use classic `C-j' and `RET'.
```